# How to find all VM/Hyper-V and then reboot them on Window Server 2012 with the use of Power-shell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, reboot

I would like to ask how to find all VM/Hyper-V on Window Server 2012 with the use of power-shell and then restart/reboot them with the use of power-shell script?

The next thing is:
I cannot even find any get command for it:
[image]

==================
Added in 2014-08-15
have find a reference link that help me a lot, just share here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848479.aspx

Comment: Have you looked in the [Hyper-V module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx)? `Get-Command -Module Hyper-V`

Comment: Yes I have tried it, seems no result is outputted. However, my Hyper-V Manager can show the VM info such as status,CPU Usage etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Powershell elevated (!) and execute following:

```
ForEach ($VM in Hyper-V\Get-VM | Where {$_.State -ne "Off") {
        Restart-Computer -ComputerName $VM.Name
}
```

Non-elevated Powershell will not return any results.

Martin

Comment: thanks,I have tried it out for nearly a month.
And your solution is possible, just wanna know when to use { and when to use (, is the concept just like C program?